# If I have a list containing names of some text files, how to create other text files with the same name but with a prefix?

Tags: c#

In my `C:` drive I have a folder called "Temp" and in 3 text files called

```
abc.txt 
pqr.txt
xyz.txt
```

Using the following code:

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Temp");
FileInfo[] Files = directory.GetFiles("*.txt"); 
List<string> filenames = new List<string>();
foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
    filenames.Add(file.Name);
}
```

I have got all the names of the files in a list. I also have a folder on the `C:` drive called "Results". Using this list, can someone tell me how I can create text files in the "Results" folder with the names:

```
result_abc.txt
result_pqr.txt
result_xyz.txt
```

Comment: You separate the folder and file names, add a prefix, combine them.

Comment: What should the contents of these newly created files in the "Results" folder be? Or should they be empty?

Comment: They should be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply do the following to create a set of new empty files from your input.

```
filenames.ForEach(f => File.Create(Path.Combine(@"C:\Results", "result_" + f)).Dispose());
```

Also, to get the `filenames`, you could have used the shorter

```
var filenames = Files.Select(fi => fi.Name).ToList();
```

instead of the `foreach`.

Finally, if you are not doing anything else with the `Files`, you could reduce this to:

```
foreach (var fi in new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Temp").EnumerateFiles("*.txt"))
    File.Create(Path.Combine(@"C:\Results", "result_" + fi.Name)).Dispose();
```